# what is the usage of completer method of future in vertx?

Tags: java, future, vert.x

I'm new in VertX framework (and reactive programming too). when I read about 'Future', I don't understand what is the usage of the 'completer' method, and when do must be used from that? I will appreciate if someone could help me?

Comment: Did you have at the Vertx documentation yet?

Comment: yes, that said 'completer return an handler completing this future'. and I understand that for example FutureImpl return 'this' because that implemented Handler<AsyncResult>, but I don't understand that when a method get completer as parameter and how it used from that?

Comment: Well, when a method reference is passed to another method/constructor it is normally meant to be called eventually, in that case most likely when the future is completed, i.e. when there's a "success" result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vert.x asynchronous methods are often defined using a `Handler<AsyncResult<X>>` parameter. This parameter is the callback invoked when the operation completes.

```
vertx.createHttpServer().listen(ar -> {
  // callback implementation
});
```

As you noticed, in the latest versions of Vert.x, a `Future<X>` implements `Handler<AsyncResult<X>>` so you can create a future and use it directly as an asynchronous operation parameter:

```
Future<HttpServer> serverFuture = Future.future();
vertx.createHttpServer().listen(future);
```

And then you can use the future methods like `map` or `compose`.

In older versions, a future wasn't a handler for asynchronous results, so you had to use the `completer` method:

```
Future<HttpServer> serverFuture = Future.future();
vertx.createHttpServer().listen(future.completer());
```

As of 3.7.0, the `completer` method is deprecated and will be removed in version 4.

Comment: thanks very much. you are right. I examined a lot and realized that handler that returned from future could be used for completion of future. actually completer returns the Handler and Handler.handle() method can take the AsyncResult as parameter and implement its methods to determine that future is completed or failed.

Comment: Future.future() is now marked as deprecated. How it changes this example? Thanks.

Comment: @petrch can you create another question with details about you problem? Thanks

Comment: Well, I have already found my answer, so I am doing absolutely fine, thanks for asking!